# Проверка наличия файла в директории

Tags: perl

Как посмотреть существует ли *.png файл в директории?

Answer (score 4):

Например, так, [**-X** A file test, where X is one of the letters listed below...](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

```
if( -f '/path/file.png' ) {
    # файл есть
}
else {
    # файла нет
}
```

Ну а вообще всё зависит от целей. Можно и попробовать открыть, если всё равно потом это делать нужно будет.

---

Если надо проверить существование *любого* файла по маске, то можно воспользоваться функцией [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @files = glob '/path/*.png';
if( @files ) {
    # какие-то файлы есть (Но не факт, что файлы, 
    # под маску могут попасть и каталоги!)
}
else {
    # файлов нет
}
```

Если получить список файлов по маске - тот же `glob` или (с отбрасыванием каталогов):

```
opendir my $dir, '/path/';
my @files = grep { -f "/path/$_" && /.*[.]png$/ } readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
```